# How do I generate a list of widgets from firebase firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through documents in firestore and create a text widget for each one.

I've figured out how to access those elements. I used debugPrint() and got the results I'm expecting, but I can't get it to display below my other widgets. I get a red screen with a ton of errors (on phone).Below is my code for what I've tried so far.

```
   QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await 
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(user.uid).collection("trails").getDocuments();
        var list = querySnapshot.documents;
list.forEach((doc) =>  debugPrint(doc.data["Trail Name"].toString()));//works
final topContentText = Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
      //these widgets are generating correctly  
      Text(
          "First Name: $firstName",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Last Name: $lastName",
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
        ),
        Text(
          "Email: $email",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, ),
        ),
     //these ones are causing my errors.
    list.forEach((doc) =>  Text(
      "Trail Name: ${doc.data["Trail Name"].toString()}",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, ),
    ),)
      ],
    );

    final topContent = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, .9)),
          child: Center(
            child: topContentText,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 8.0,
          top: 60.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[topContent, bottomContent],
      ),
    );
```

The screen on my device lights up red with errors on creating child widgets, when I'm expecting it to display the Trail Name(s) below the other info. I only included necessary code, but could include more (such as the widget's build method) if needed. Thanks for any assistance. I'm new to flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the map function:

```
  List<Widget> _widgets = list.map((doc) =>  Text(
    "Trail Name: ${doc.data["Trail Name"].toString()}",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, ),
  ),).toList();
```

And then for the children of the column, just add that list to the list you specify, like:

```
children: [ ... ] + _widgets;
```

Comment: ah ha, that did it. Thanks!